# R's pipe() function and Ubuntu console gives different result

Tags: r, linux, docker, ubuntu

I am using R in my Ubuntu machine with latest configuration

In R, I get below result:

```
> read.fwf(pipe('ps -ef | grep /var/lib/docker/'), width = 60)
                                                            V1
1 root     29155 29151  0 11:18 pts/0    00:00:00 sh -c ps -ef
2 root     29157 29155  0 11:18 pts/0    00:00:00 grep /var/li
```

However in Ubuntu console I get different result

```
ps -ef | grep /var/lib/docker/
root     29150  2509  0 11:17 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto /var/lib/docker/
```

I wanted R to fetch `PID` of `/var/lib/docker/`, which is according to Ubuntu 2509

Can anyone help me understand why I am getting different result and how to fetch the PID number correctly?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ps()` in the ps package.  This function outputs a data.frame with the process id information.

```
library(ps)

pid_df <- ps()
pid_df$pid[grep("docker", pid_df$name)]
```

or in one line:

```
subset(ps(), grep("docker", name))$pid
```